# "Show" anchor point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, ios6

I'm using a custom image (which is 360 x 276 so not proportional) and I'm rotating it with an animation.
The anchor point is not just (0,.5) or (1,0), it's something like (.23423, .912314). Is there any way to show, where the anchor point currently is? Or setting it in InterfaceBuilder? Currently I'm just trying to reach the correct CGPoint by testing different values, but I didn't get the perfect one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simple set it in IB, unfortunately. In your case, I would use some image processing application to find out at what coordinate you need the image to rotate and then do the math:

`84,3228 / 360 = 0.24423`

Not necessarily brilliant, but workable I would say.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
CGPoint anchorPosition = CGPointMake(
                    imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width*anchorPoint.x,
                    imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height*anchorPoint.y);
```

You can refer to http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html